# Adding constrain to check if there exist a combination of pairs such that it statisfy a ratio?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint-programming, or-tools

Lets say I have a set of items in a set `x0, ..., x14` each consisting its own values `v0, ..., v14`

I am trying to at most 8 items such that I get the maximum value.

I am able to get the following maximization problem

```
max v0*x0 + ... + v14*x14
s.t.
x0 + ... + x14 <= 8
0 <= x0 <= 1
.
.
0 <= x14 <= 1
```

However, I need to add another constrains, that is for the items chosen, I should be able to pair them such that their ratio is less than 2.

i.e. lets say that the item chosen is `x0, x1, x3, x4, x8, x9, x10, x11` with the maximum value they would also have a configuration of pairing such that,

```
(v0 * x0)/(v1 * x1)  <= 2, 
(v3 * x3)/(v9 * x9)  <= 2,
(v4 * x4)/(v11 * x11)<= 2,
(v8 * x8)/(v10 * x10)<= 2,
```

Any idea on how to formulate the above set of constrains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can precompute the valid pairs, and their value (the sum of the 2 elements)

So there are at most 14 * 13 / 2 potential ordered pairs, much less valid ones.

You need to select 4 pairs subject to the constraint that once a pair is selected, any pairs involving the same elements cannot be selected. This is a simple at most one constraints on 14 subsets of pairs.

```
for all item in items:
  sum(bool_pair for all bool_pair involving item) <= 1
```

You can use CP-SAT or the linear solver wrapper to solve this.